# permissions of id_rsa.pub as 644 (-rw-r--r--) but the parent folder .ssh as 700 (drwx------)

Tags: ssh, permissions, file-permissions

I have a use case where my program needs to read the `id_rsa.pub` file under `/root/.ssh` folder.

The default permissions for id_rsa.pub are (`-rw-r--r--`) and for .ssh folder they are (`drwx------`)

This is in line with the recommendations from the [official SSH man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html).

The problem:

Any group or a user cannot read the `id_rsa.pub` file because the parent folder (.ssh) does not have the execute permission on a group or a user.

1. What would be the point of having of such a permission combination? No user or group can read the `id_rsa.pub` file without proper permissions on `.ssh` folder.
2. Will there be any concerns with changing permissions for `.ssh` folder from 700 to 710? (to enable my program to read the `id_rsa.pub` file). This is also inline with the man page recommendations above.

Comment: In my experience the permissions for `.ssh/` are `drwx------` and the `id_rsa.pub` has `-rw-------` for the reasons you outline. No clue why you have the `id_rsa.pub` set to `-rw-r--r--` since it could never be read by others anyway in `.ssh/`. Maybe you should clarify why you need a program that is not owned by you to have access to `id_rsa.pub` in `.ssh/` to begin with? That said, `id_rsa.pub` is what one can share anywhere since it is the public key. My guess is it is just in `.ssh/` for convenience. You should be able to just copy it to wherever you want for your application’s use.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I think 644 is normal on a public key eg it's mentioned here too https://gist.github.com/denisgolius/d846af3ad5ce661dbca0335ec35e3d39 and i think i might have seen that as a default after ssh-keygen

Comment: Voting to close unless more details on the application are provided. The reason? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) question. The premise is an application that is somehow _not_ run by the user is supposed to somehow access the user’s `.ssh/` directory when `id_rsa.pub` is the part of a key that can be publicly shared. It makes no sense to me unless a clear explanation can be provided as to why the application needs to behave this way.

Comment: I would just place the pub key file somewhere that can be reached by non-root users (e.g. `/whatever`) and make symlinks anywhere (including `/root/.ssh/`) I need.

Answer (score 0):

These permissions are hard-coded in OpenSSH. Keep in mind that you could run `ssh-keygen` from anywhere, saving keys to any writable location. By using these permissions, `ssh-keygen` makes sure the private key is protected anywhere.

If you have a program running that needs your public SSH key, it’s probably a good idea to just copy they public key elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the point of having a 644/664 access on the `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file is to make it easy to be shared from there (its point of creation and reference).  This access is based on the user `umask` setting.

You would normally make a hand-off copy to where-ever it is required. As a convenience and general rule the `ssh-copy-id` script should be used whenever possible to hand-off your public key to peers.